# Реализация отсчета от нуля и до нужного значения на js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Нужно реализовать отсчет в блоках[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что бы при загрузке страницы отсчет начинался с 0 и до определенного показателя,  есть ли какие то библиотеки или готовые решения?

Comment: счётчики называется ..ищите в yandex, к примеру  https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Counting-Up-To-Numerical-Values-On-Scroll-jQuery-Countup-js/

Comment: закрывать не надо  так как вопроса подобного не было ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какие вам еще библиотеки нужны, если в простейшем случае для решения несколько строк кода надо? искать дольше будете, чем код писать.

```js
var h = setInterval(function(){
           $(".c.active").each(function(){
               var c = +$(this).data('current') || 0;
               var max = +$(this).data('max');
               if(++c <= max){
                    $(this).data('current', c).text(c);
               }
               else $(this).removeClass('active');
           });
           if(!$(".c.active").length){
               clearInterval(h);
               console.log('the end');
           }
        }, 100);
```

```css
.c { 
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c active" data-max="100"></div>
<div class="c active" data-max="50"></div>
<div class="c active" data-max="150"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так можно, например:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('div');

function draw(t){
  el.forEach(el => {
    let d = el.dataset
    el.textContent = Math.min(t/+d.delay, +d.value).toFixed(+d.precision)
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<div data-value=100 data-delay=100 data-precision=1></div>
<div data-value=200 data-delay=50  data-precision=0></div>
```